# Why do I get an "Access to disposed closure" warning with this code

Tags: c#, closures

I have the following code (using ImageSharp):

```
using (var I = Image.Load<Rgb24>(Picture))
{
    // calculate the hash
    var T = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CalculateHash(I));
    var Hash = T.Result; <- I put this as a test

    ...
}
```

I am getting an "access to disposed closure" warning with 'I' on the CalculateHash method.

This is a simplified version of the code; in the normal code I do a few different processes in parallel and wait for them all to complete.

In this example, I explicitly wait for the result of the task within the 'using' context, so the closure should not be disposed before the task is complete.

Why am I getting this message?

Comment: CalculateHash is finished by then since I'm collecting the task result. You mean that CalculateHash could spawn another task/thread using 'I'?

Comment: Why are you asking a thread pool thread to do the work if you're just going to immediately wait for it?  If you want to do the work synchronously, just run the method and be done with it.

Comment: Seems like the compiler is only checking the control flow at the point of call.

Comment: @servy: it's for the example (as explained in paragraph 2), in the regular code I have several tasks working on the same image

Comment: @MatthewWatson: it's a resharper warning, I'll talk with them because the message doesn't indicate access to a disposed closure but that the code has the potential to do it

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains offers some help here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2018.2/AccessToDisposedClosure.html

It appears that explicitly waiting for the result of the task within the 'using' context is irrelevant; you could still be hanging on to I outside of the "using" scope.